# С++11: использование auto для константного итератора

Tags: c++, c++11

При итерации по массиву без модификации элементов какой вариант объявления итератора лучше?

```
std::vector<std::string> array;
...
for (auto it : array) { //#1
}
for (auto& it : array) { //#2
}
for (const auto it : array) { //#3
}
for (const auto& it : array) { //#4
}
```

**UPD:**

Спасибо @Abyx:

```
for (auto&& it : array) { //#5
}


it - не итератор (спасибо @borisbn). Как его лучше назвать?
```

Comment: Я Вас разочарую - http://ideone.com/fDErNo

Comment: Спасибо, согласен it - не итератор, и вопрос сформулирован немного нергамотно. Есть ли лучший термин для it - это не итератор и не индекс, а что?

Comment: @OliverTwist: переменная цикла? текущий элемент?

Comment: В последнем варианте будет ссылка на элемент массива.  Традиционно сокращается до itm (i - index, it - iterator, itm - item).

Answer (score 1):

Если хочется явно сказать, что нужны константные элементы, то можно написать

```
for (const auto& it : array)
```

Но лучше использовать "универсальную ссылку"

```
for (auto&& it : array)
```

потому что универсальные ссылки сами выводят `const`, и его не надо прибивать гвоздями в коде.

Comment: Можете развернуть ответ: в чем преимущества _курсив_универсальной_курсив_ ссылки?
По мне так константная ссылка более универсальна - можно использовать с константыми и модифицируемыми массивами.

Comment: А можете пояснить как "универсальные сслыки сами выводят `const`"? Или дать хорошую сслыку на соответствующий материал?

Comment: Если константность в цикле нужна и есть выбор между 2 вариантами, то лучше использовать вариант с `const`, чтобы 1) явно показать намерения; 2) получить ошибку компиляции, если что

Answer (score 0):

4-ый вариант, чтобы избежать копирования

Comment: Есть ли преимущества перед вариантом №2?

Comment: Как я понимаю, во всех случаях будет const iterator или `itertor`, но не `const_iterator`. Есть ли возможность как-то это исправить?

Comment: думаю, что первый вариант - самый лучший. Дайте компилятору вывести типы самостоятельно. А вот когда бенчмарк покажет, что здесь слабое место - вот тогда и нужно заниматься оптимизацией.

Представьте себе человека, который через много лет будет смотреть в код и скажет "а зачем он тут так изголялся? видимо тут что то важное" А там обычный код, который запускается раз в сто лет.

Comment: Не согласен: это не преждевременная оптимизация, а хороший стиль по умолчанию, который должен быть стандартизован. Например, до С++11 было стандартом передавать объекты по константной ссылке и без результатов тестов на производительность.

Comment: а разве auto не может быть выведен как константный итератор? или ссылка?

Comment: "константный итератор" это 'const iterator' или 'const_iterator'?
Уверен, что если и может, то не будет.

Comment: если Вы так переживаете по этому поводу и для Вас это принципиально - избегайте auto, а то мало чего оно там выведет и всегда пишите ручками длинные триады:)

Comment: А с чего Вы взяли, что тип будет итератор ? http://ideone.com/fDErNo

Comment: просто посмотрел на предыдущие комментарии - там пишут о итераторах:)